# Apply nested Routing in Reactjs so only new component Show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

Hi the thing i want to achieve here is, i have some components like header and side menu that are all the same in every page, so i'm trying to only render the components that are going to be different but i can't seem to get it right,
Here is my index.js

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} >
       </Route>
       <Route exact path="/SignUp" component={SignUp} >
       </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

and here is the Sign Up component

```
<Router>
     <Header />
     <Switch>
          <Route path="/signUp/hi">
                        hi
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signUp/hey">
                        hey
         </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

When i put `/signup/hi` i expect to see a page with header and a hi inside it, but instead it's a blank page, so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove exact attribute from /SignUp route as you want to match anything after /SignUp.

```
<Route path="/SignUp" component={SignUp} />
```

Also, use same casing for route mentioned in `index.js` and the one mentioned in component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in your index file that all pages starts with SignUp should go to SignUp, like this:

```
<Route exact path="/SignUp/*" component={SignUp} >
```

Or change `exact path` to `path` for SignUp route